# Django can upload to S3 but not Get from S3

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto3, python-django-storages

I have configured django to use s3 to hold media files. I can from the application upload files and they are stored on the s3, however if i try to view these media  files i get this error.

```
<Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
</Message>
```

I know GET requests are enabled as I can use Postman to get the images using the same credentials. So I'm not entirely sure whats wrong.

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/staticfiles/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/image_library/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'PLACEHOLDER'

AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'PLACEHOLDER'

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'childcaredevapp'

AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False

AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = "s3v4"

AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'eu-central-1'

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

Answer (score 2):

So... Long story short, i achieved it to create correct signature by removing `AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = "s3v4"` line. Looks like they dont match for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error, I solve it by adding the **AWS_S3_ADDRESSING_STYLE** variable:

```
AWS_S3_ADDRESSING_STYLE = "virtual"
```